# Beautifullsoup Amazon Product Detail

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I can't scrape the "Product Details" section (scrolling down the webpage you'll find it) html by using requests or requests_html.
Find_all returns a 0 size object... Any Help?

```
from requests import session
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
#s = session()
r = s.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B094HWN66Y")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
len(soup.find_all("div", {"id":"detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div"}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product details with different information:

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

cookies = {'session': '131-1062572-6801905'}
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B094HWN66Y",headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
print(r)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
key = [x.get_text(strip=True).replace('\u200f\n','').replace('\u200e','').replace(':\n','').replace('\n', '').strip() for x in soup.select('ul.a-unordered-list.a-nostyle.a-vertical.a-spacing-none.detail-bullet-list > li > span > span.a-text-bold')][:13]
#print(key)

value = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('ul.a-unordered-list.a-nostyle.a-vertical.a-spacing-none.detail-bullet-list > li > span > span:nth-child(2)')]
#print(value)


product_details = {k:v for  k, v, in zip(key, value)}
print(product_details)
```

Output:

```
{'ASIN': 'B094HWN66Y', 'Publisher': 'Boldwood Books (September 7, 2021)', 'Publication date': 
'September 7, 2021', 'Language': 'English', 'File size': '1883 KB', 'Text-to-Speech': 'Enabled', 'Screen Reader': 'Supported', 'Enhanced typesetting': 'Enabled', 'X-Ray': 'Enabled', 'Word 
Wise': 'Enabled', 'Print length': '332 pages', 'Page numbers source ISBN': '1800487622', 'Lending': 'Not Enabled'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to scrape the title of the product using `bs4` and `requests`, easily expandable to getting other info from the product.

The reason yours doesn't work is your request has no headers so Amazon realises your a bot and doesn't want you scraping their site. This is shown by your request being returned as `<Response [503]>` and explained in `r.text`.

I believe Amazon have an API for this (that they'd probably like you to use) but it'll be fine to scrape like this for small-scale stuff.

```
import requests
import bs4

# Amazon don't like you scrapeing them however these headers should stop them from noticing a small number of requests
HEADERS = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})


def main():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B094HWN66Y"
    title = get_title(url)
    print("The title of %s is: %s" % (url, title))


def get_title(url: str) -> str:
    """Returns the title of the amazon product."""
    # The request
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

    # Parse the content
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": 'productTitle'}).string

    return title


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:
`The title of https://www.amazon.com/dp/B094HWN66Y is:  Will They, Won't They?`

Comment: The title is not what I'm looking for, and I have no proble in scraping the title too... if you scroll down the page you'll find a window called product details with different information, and that's what I'm looking for